# Combine two portrait layouts in one landscape

Tags: android, android-layout

I designed my application for phones mostly so all my layouts are portraits. However I think I can place my two portrait layouts standing side by side making one landscape layout for a tablet. Anyone has an idea how to make it simple? Generally I assume I can use table layout, however most samples going in row route, when I need columns one, so two columns should have equal width. Another wish if I could utilize simple include statement to include nested layouts instead of copying them, because if I decide to change one, then I need to replicate my changes in tablet layout which is generally bad practice of code duplication.

Comment: Have you thought of using [Fragment](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to use LinearLayout with weightSum=2 and horizontal orientation and then you can use `include` tags for your portrait layouts with weights 1.